# discord.js sending the api response as a bold text

Tags: node.js, api, discord.js, text-formatting, bold

How to parse api response into bold text message to the discord channel?

```
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get('ChannelID')
channel.send('Price is: ' + price.toFixed(2).bold(), { "parse_mode": "HTML" });
```

This code will return message
`Price is: <b>1.33</b>` and won't parse the text into bold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send it just like in a normal Discord message with the two *. So it will look like

```
let channel = guild.channels.cache.get(`ChannelID`);
channel.send(`Price is **${price.toFixed(2)}**`);
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked, i never though i can use placeholder in message like that.